# Triangle style output, incrementing max line length

Tags: php

The output that I want:

> - 1
> - 2 3
> - 4 5 6
> - 7 8 9 10
> - 11 12 13 14 15
> - 16 17 18 19 20 21
> - 22 23 24 25 26 27 28

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php
        $i;
        $a = 1;
        $b = 0;

        for($i = 1; $i < 29; $i++){
          echo $i;

          if ($i == $a){
            echo "</li><li>";

            $a = $i + 2 + $b;
            $b++;
          }
       }
       ?>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

Is it possible to get rid of `$b` and make it simpler ?

Comment: Are the ul and li tags supposed to be part of the code, or is there a formatting issue?

Comment: @Jamal <ul> and <li> are just for making lists display in HTML.

Comment: If they're not supposed to be part of the PHP code, then I can fix the formatting.

Comment: @Jamal No it's OK, the code would not work without them

Comment: Thanks for all great answers. I always forget that what may be clear in head is not clear for the next one who reads my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to see what `$b` really means in this code.
It turns out to be something like this:
*"number of items on the next line minus 1"*

And also `$a`: 
*"last number on the next line"*

So I came up with these not amazing but better variable names:

```
$next_last_number = 1;
$next_number_of_items = 1;
```

Note that I changed the meaning of `$b`,
now it means "number of items" instead of "number of items minus 1",
and to reflect this, now I initialize it to 1, naturally.

And to make it work, I changed the incrementing logic inside the loop:

```
$next_number_of_items++;
$next_last_number = $i + $next_number_of_items;
```

So, when you reached the last item on a line,
your next target is `$next_number_of_items + 1` items on the next line,
which gives the number `$i + $next_number_of_items`.

The magic number 2 in the original code is now gone,
and you have a more natural logical flow.
It was simply the variable names that lead me on this path,
that's why naming is extremely important.

A few other improvements I'd suggest:

- Remove the pointless statement `$i;`
- Add a line break after `</li>` to make the HTML source code of the output easier to read

The complete improved code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php
        $next_last_number = 1;
        $next_number_of_items = 1;

        for ($i = 1; $i < 29; $i++) {
          echo $i, " ";

          if ($i == $next_last_number) {
            echo "</li>\n<li>";

            $next_number_of_items++;
            $next_last_number = $i + $next_number_of_items;
          }
       }
       ?>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

The output of your program is not as you are saying. This is the real output:

> ```
> 1
> 23
> 456
> 78910
> 1112131415
> 161718192021
> 22232425262728
> ```

To get your desired output, you can change this:

```
echo $i;
```

To:

```
echo $i." ";
```

This will append the extra space after each iteration.

---

### `$a`

`a` is a poor variable name. You could make your code much clearer if you gave it a meaningful name, like `$countOfNumbersToDisplay`. Sure, it's a lot longer to type, but it indicates your intention much more clearly than `$a`.

Same goes for `$b`.

---

### Avoid magic numbers

This is not very easy to understand:

```
      if ($i == $a){
        echo "</li><li>";

        $a = $i + 2 + $b;
        $b++;
      }
```

Why `+ 2`? This really could use some clarification. I suggest to make `2` a constant with a meaningful name earlier in your code.

Answer (score 4):

With a small amount of code, there's not much to review, but nonetheless:

---

You name your variables letters: `$a`, `$b`, instead of what they physically represent: `$maxValue`, `$maxLength`.

---

When you declare `$a` and `$b`, you also declare `$i` as an empty variable. Don't do that.
The `for` loop can declare it `for` you.

---

By incrementing `$b` or `$maxLength` (*as I suggest you call it*) before you perform the change on `$a` or `$maxValue` (*as I suggest you call it*), you can remove the magic number \$2\$ and make it a good ole \$1\$.

---

When `echo`ing `$i`, you actually don't space them out like your example.
Try this instead: `echo "$i ";`

---

Don't forget to add whitespace around your `for` loop:

> ```
> for($i = 1; $i < 29; $i++){
>   ^^                     ^^
> ```

into: `for ($i = 1; $i < 29; $i++) {`

---

End result of:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php
        $maxValue = 1;
        $maxLength = 1;

        for ($i = 1; $i < 29; $i++) {
            echo "$i ";

            if ($maxValue == $i) {
                echo "</li>\n<li>";
                $maxLength++;
                $maxValue = $i + $maxLength;
            }
        }
        ?>
    </li>   
</ul>
```